# Displacement is blocky

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, displacement

**I am trying to do some Moon renders using NASA's CGI Moon Kit**: https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4720

[image]

Said kit has **super high-res color and displacement textures** (27000x13000), but **this is what I'm getting up close**:

[image]

**Is there a way to smooth it out?**
Even though a 27k displacement texture which weighs 1,06 GB shouldn't even look like that in the first place...

Shade Smooth is (of course) enabled. Auto Smooth is off.
I tried adding a bunch of Subdivision Surface modifiers, but they didn't help at all.
Someone said I should use Adaptive Subdivision, but I couldn't find it in the Subdivision Surface modifier panel.
I also tried plugging the same displacement texture in the Normal input of the Principled BSDF through a Bump node, but the result was even worse.

Please help me!

Comment: What is your setup for displacement? Share your blend without textures.

Comment: Here it is: https://we.tl/t-2A6J5PDq3s

Comment: These lines are visible also on the original displace texture.

Comment: Looks like the interpolation between pixels is off. In the image texture node of your material if your interpolation mode is set to "Closest" try out another mode (Smart or Cubic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are visible also in the original texture. So to get rid of this you would have to use some image editor to compensate it. Here I used Photoshop's Box Blur filter with range 1 px that wasn't enough so I used it twice, but you loose some details.

Original
[image]

Box Blur 1 px
[image]

Box Blur 1 px applied twice
[image]

---

There are probably better algorithms for reconstruction or pattern removal like some **FFT Fast - Fourier Transform** (they are like a magic in some cases) ... so here are some examples

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9ziTuJ3OCw
- https://www.wirebiters.com/salt-pepper-image-denoising-using-matlab/
- [https://www.cs.unm.edu/~brayer/vision/fourier.html](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Ebrayer/vision/fourier.html)

Ten years ago I used some FFT script for Photoshop, but it is too far to remember anything, sorry :)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the answer!
Where do you see the lines? I opened both textures but I can't see them at all. https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4720

Comment: In the original texture are lines in vertical direction https://imgur.com/VWPgCv6 They aren't so clearly visible as in render because they are not shaded. These displacement B&W images with high bit-depth consists visually from a small steps in grey color that produce a "big" step in elevation to be able cover whole range of high transformed into greyscale, but I think you can see them if adjust image Exposure.

Comment: Oh I see... could it also be an interpolation issue, as Gorgious said?

Comment: You can try it by your self :) What I tried - NO. Interpolation is set to Linear, it is not off and others doesn't help either in this kind of zoom.

Comment: Okay! I'll try Box Blur then, thank you!

Comment: I'm not saying BoxBlur is the best option (as you can see you loose details even with this 1px), I just wanted spot it is an image issue not the material setup. Good luck.

Comment: One last question: could you send me the blurred file? I can't find Box Blur in Photoshop... I have the Italian version so I don't know which method to pick since the translation is different.

Comment: Sfocatura selezione (https://helpx.adobe.com/it/photoshop/using/filter-effects-reference.html#blur_filters)

Comment: Grazie! So do I just blur the displacement texture by 1 or 2 pixels and use that file?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, edited description on image. The filter is used with 1 px but twice, I just wanted to use small range as much as possible. You can test others to try what works the best for you, probably smart blur can be also helpful. Or sharp it later ...

Comment: Okay, I'll apply Box Blur twice with 1 px.

Comment: Here's what happened... before (https://imgur.com/a/HgpW09U) and after (https://imgur.com/a/DFPlrZd). I don't understand why there's no displacement in some areas...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118499/discussion-between-vklidu-and-blenderhotspot).